# typeDefs must be a string | GraphQL

Tags: nodejs, express, graphql

Estoy trabajando con Graphql, al momento de configurar mi archivo schema.js de la siguiente manera:

```
//* Imports
import { resolvers } from './resolvers';
import { importSchema } from 'graphql-import';
import { makeExecutableSchema } from 'graphql-tools';

// Importar Schemas
const typeDefs = importSchema('./schema.graphql');
const schema = makeExecutableSchema({typeDefs, resolvers});

export { schema };
```

Obtengo un mensaje de error en la terminal, con lo siguiente:

> C:\Users\ID139\Documents\Projects\support-graphql\node_modules\graphql-tools\dist\generate\buildSchemaFromTypeDefinitions.js:15
>
> throw new _1.SchemaError("typeDefs must be a string, array or schema AST, got " + type);
>               ^
>
> [Error: typeDefs must be a string, array or schema AST, got object]
>   [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Alguna idea de como solucionarlo?

Comment: Nunca he usado esas herramientas, pero, por el error, yo probaría a quitar el `importSchema( )` y dejar solo la cadena `'./schema.graphql'`

Comment: O, como alternativa, probaría a cargar tal cual el archivo de marras: `typeDefs = fs.readFileSync( './chema.graphql', { encoding: 'utf-8' } );`

Comment: Se supone que para eso sirve `{ importSchema }` pero no funciona, de ninguna de las maneras que proporcionas... es algo raro y no encuentro informacion de ello en Internet

Comment: En el vistazo rápido que le he echado a los ejemplos de la herramienta, `typeDefs` siempre es una cadena con la definición de los tipos, por eso los comentarios. Siento no poder ser de mas ayuda, nunca lo he usado :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tuve el mismo problema y me di cuenta que es por la version que tenia, instala esta version espero te ayude

```
npm install graphql-import@0.7.1
```